# how to retrieve and post the dynamic checkbox values to next page in php

Tags: php

I want to post the textbox values which is in the foreach loop,How can I post and retrieve the values from one page to another page. please help me on this.
how retrieve my posted textbox values on my retrieve.php page

```
<?php
      $months=array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December");

      for($o=0;$o<12;$o++)
      {
  $monthname=$months[$o];
   $get=mysql_query("select * from workupdate where Empname='$empname'and Designation='$designation'");
  $i=1;
  echo "<td>";
  echo $monthname;
  echo "</td>";
  while($res=mysql_fetch_array($get)) 
  {
   //foreach($sepqua

   $getres=array();
   $getres=explode(":", $res[$monthname]) ;
   $sepqua=array();
   //$sepqua=explode("-",$getres);


   //echo '<input type="text" name="sno" value='..'>';
   foreach($getres as $expres) 

        {
        if(!empty($expres))
         {
          $t=0;
          echo"month$t$o";
         echo"<td>";
         echo '<input type="text" name="month$t$o" value='.$expres.'>' ;    
         echo"</td>";
         $t++;
        }
      }
   $i++;}
   ?>
```

retrieve.php

```
<?php
     $month=array();
for($k=0;$k<=12;$k++)
{
    $t=0;
   $getmonth="month".$t.$k;
   $month=array();
   echo $_POST[$getmonth];
   //echo $month;
    $t++;
   foreach($month as $value)
   {

   echo"<td>";
   echo $value;
   echo"</td>";
//echo"</tr>";
   }

}
?>
```

Comment: You could make it a lot easier for yourself if you use arrays in your html. Then you can simply loop over the POST variable: `<input type="text" name="month[$t][$o]" value='.$expres.'>`. Now `$_POST['month']` is a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: how can I retrieve the array values on next page @jeroen i got some error:"Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\task2\updateweightagevalues.php on line 68
Array" can you help me over this